# Force height of div which has display: table-cell

Tags: html, css

I have 2 table-cell divs next to each other. The right one has fixed height of 75px (which I can't change) and the left one needs to have height 70px. To force the height on the left div, I used `min-height`, `max-height`, `height` and `line-height` but none of them helped.

In the following picture, what I have is on the left and what I need is on the right.

**What I have** .......................... **What I need**

[image]

**Is it possible to be done with two divs having `display: table-cell;`?**

PS. I need to do it using `table-cell` so please suggest other solutions only if it can't be done.

Thanks

Comment: Table cells in the same row are always the same height. Could you not use a nested element instead of setting the height on the cell?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It seems like I will end up doing this.

Comment: @AntBlackShaw gave the decisive hint, and I made a working pen from it, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible, at least directly.

As explained in [§17.2.1 Anonymous table objects](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes), your table-cells are [consecutive](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#x21):

> Two sibling boxes are consecutive if they have no intervening siblings
>   other than, optionally, an anonymous inline containing only white
>   spaces. A sequence of sibling boxes is consecutive if each box in the
>   sequence is consecutive to the one before it in the sequence.

Therefore, they will generate common table-row and table:

> Generate missing parents:
>
> 1. For each 'table-cell' box C in a sequence of consecutive internal table and 'table-caption' siblings, if C's parent is not a 'table-row'
>      then generate an anonymous 'table-row' box around C and all
>      consecutive siblings of C that are 'table-cell' boxes.
> 2. For each proper table child C in a sequence of consecutive proper table children, if C is misparented then generate an anonymous 'table'
>      or 'inline-table' box T around C and all consecutive siblings of C
>      that are proper table children. (If C's parent is an 'inline' box,
>      then T must be an 'inline-table' box; otherwise it must be a 'table'
>      box.)

And then, according to [§17.5 Visual layout of table contents](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-layout),

> Internal table elements generate rectangular boxes with content and
>   borders. [...]
>
> The visual layout of these boxes is governed by a rectangular,
>   irregular grid of rows and columns. Each box occupies a whole number
>   of grid cells

You can assume that this number is 1. It could be more, but

> CSS 2.1 does not define how the number of spanned rows or columns is
>   determined

Then, the two cells will have the same height.

If you don't want that, you can get rid of `display: table-cell` and use other approaches instead.

For example, you can consider using `display: inline-table`. If your elements don't have other tabular elements inside them, they will generate anonymous table-cells which will wrap the content.

```css
#foo, #bar {
  display: inline-table;
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 70px;
}
#foo { height: 30px; }
#bar { height: 75px; }
```

```html
<div id="foo">Foo</div>
<div id="bar">Bar</div>
```

Alternatively, if the elements must be table-cells, you can insert non-whitespace content between them. This way they won't be consecutive, so they will generate different table elements.

However, remember that if the parent of the cells is a block, the generated tables will be table boxes, so the cells will be in different lines. To avoid that, place the cells in an inline element. This way the generated tables will be inline-table boxes:

```css
body { display: inline; }
#foo, #bar {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 70px;
}
#foo { height: 30px; }
#bar { height: 75px; }
```

```html
<div id="foo">I am a table-cell</div>
<span><!-- I allow the cells to have different heights --></span>
<div id="bar">I am a table-cell</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to guess at what's a good solution here without the full CSS and HTML to review.

Mocking it up locally based on what you describe; if I float the left table-cell div (e.g `float: left;`) and then set it's height that changes the height of just that cell but that might have other side effects for your set up that I can't foresee in my mock up.

I checked in FireFox and Chromium and floating the table-cell div allowed me to set separate heights in both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that it was quite difficult to guess my full CSS, but I think I will end up putting an element into that cell and set the height of the nested element to the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Firefox at least: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVRjZR I recommend you do the browser testing before you use this in a production environment since I assume table-cells aren't meant to float.

```css
.table {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
  width: 300px;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 150px;
}
.cell-a {
  background-color: #a88;
  height: 50px;
}
.cell-b {
  background-color: #8a8;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell cell-a"></div>
  <div class="cell cell-b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Though this _looks_ like it works in reality floating the divs removes the cell-like properties of `display: table-cell`. For example you can no longer vertically align content - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbKMGz If you are going to use a fixed width and float you may as well just use a block element